What is the frequency setting in an oozie coordinator.xml for bi-monthly
I'm attempting to set up a new coordinator file with a execute bi-monthly frequency.  Is this setting possible and if so, what does that coord: setting look like?
I know how to use daily or monthly, but so far, the best I can find is to modify the number of days to 14 or 15.
${coord:days(15)} --> minutes in 15 full days from the current date
